# Surprising solution to recurrence relation $f(n+1)=\frac{a}{f(n)}+b$

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, recurrence-relations

Let $a\neq b\neq c\in\Bbb R$ be given. Suppose that we are looking for a sequence of real numbers $f(1),f(2),\dots$ satisfying for all $n\in\Bbb N$

$$f(n+1) = \frac{(b-a)\cdot(a-c)}{f(n)} +2 a - b - c.$$

WolframAlpha provides the general solution
$$f(n)=\frac{\lambda (a-c)^2 \frac1{(b-a)^n}+(a-b)^2 \frac1{(c-a)^n}}{\lambda (a-c)\frac1{(b-a)^n}+(a-b)\frac1{(c-a)^n}}$$

where $\lambda\in\Bbb R$ can be chosen arbitrarily as long as the above expression is well-defined.

*My question.* Is there some more general theory behind this? Because currently it is very surprising to me how my recurrence relation has such an explicit general solution. For example, is there a theory behind solutions to 
$$f(n+1)=\frac a{f(n)}+b$$
?

Comment: Note that you can find complex numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $a=-\alpha\beta$, $-b=\alpha+\beta$. Then note that your relation can be written as $f(n+1)=(\beta-0)(0-\alpha)/f(n)+(2 \cdot 0-\beta-\alpha)$.

Comment: @Mindlack You are right! I can construct a solution for the bottom relation from the top one since the solution seems to work also for complex coefficients :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is, in fact, a general explicit solution to the recurrence relation
$$x_{n+1}=b+\frac{a}{x_n}$$
and it is given by the following explicit formula in terms of $x_0$:
$$x_n=\frac{(x_0-k)(\frac{k}{b-k}-1)}{(\frac{k}{b-k})^n(\frac{k}{b-k}-1)+\frac{1}{b-k}((\frac{k}{b-k})^n-1)(x_0-k)}+k$$
where
$$k=\frac{b + \sqrt{b^2+4a}}{2}$$
For a proof of this assertion, see [my blog post](https://franklin.dyer.me/post/77) which treats a variety of first-order recurrences (using functional iteration).

Comment: You sure you linked the intended blog post?

Comment: @DanielV Sorry, the link is fixed now. :)